# Realloc sets all indexes the same data

Tags: c, file, realloc

```
FILE *fd;
char **lines = NULL;

int err = fopen_s(&fd, filename, "r");

if (err != 0) {
    printf("Nao foi possivel abrir o ficheiro %s ...\n", filename);
    return;
}

char nextline[1024];
int counter = 0;

while (fgets(nextline, sizeof(nextline), fd)) {
    if (strlen(nextline) < 1) {
        continue;
    }

    lines = (char**)realloc(lines, (counter+1) * sizeof(*lines));
    lines[counter] = nextline;



    counter++;
}

fclose(fd);
*numElements = counter;

//IN HERE IT SHOWS ME THE SAME FOR ALL THE PLAYERS FROM 300 DIFFERENT PLAYERS WHY IS THAT???
printf_s("\n\n%s\n", lines[299]);
printf_s("%s\n", lines[298]);
```

I can't figure the problem.
First realloc was deleting the old buffer now it is literally copying the same data to all the 300 indexes.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Of course they are all the same, they all point to the same buffer. You need to copy the data out of the buffer if you don't want it overwritten by the next line. Realloc does exactly what it should, but this line assigns the same value to each index in turn. `lines[counter] = nextline;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `lines` is basically an array of pointers. And all pointers in the array are pointing to the first element of the very same `nextline` array.

The assignment

```
lines[counter] = nextline;
```

is only assigning the *pointer*, it doesn't do a deep copy or duplicating the string currently in `nextline`.

You might want to use the `strdup` function instead of just assigning pointers:

```
lines[counter] = strdup(nextline);
```

Remember to `free` the strings you `strdup` later.

If you know how arrays and pointers interact, a simple [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) should have told you this in just a few seconds. And if you don't understand that you're just assigning pointers then you need to go back to your text books or lecture notes.

Comment: The problem is really that. I am not really good working with C but this is for classes.
Yes I could do it the easiest way knowing how many rows the file has but I don't like to make it so closed and with it I learned something else.

Thanks